# How do I bind generic types with inheritance using custom logic?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

I have a generic interface `IService` which is concretely implemented by three or four implementations.

```
public interface IService {
   void HandleRequest( RequestData data );
}

public class AService : IService {
   public void HandleRequest( RequestData data ) {
   }
}

public class BService : IService {
   public void HandleRequest( RequestData data ) {
   }
}
```

The rules to choose a concrete implementation versus a different one are actually implemented into a method which analyze the input object (`RequestData`) and based on some data coming from the database choose the correct concrete class.

I need now to do constructor injection in a controller class and would like to configure Ninject to handle the instance creation of those objects like in the following sample

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public MyController( IService service ) {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to write such an extension to support Ninject in the decision process? I am thinking to something like this

```
Bind<IService>().To<AService>().IfConditionIsTrue( new CustomProvider() );
Bind<IService>().To<BService>().IfConditionIsTrue( new CustomProvider() );

public class CustomProvider {
    public bool ApplyCustomLogic() {
        RequestData rd = GetParameter();
        [...]
        //custom logic implementation here..
    }
}
```

Also, how I can create an instance on the fly by leveraging ninject functionalities? For example, inside a method at a certain time, I need an instance of `IService`. How can I ask ninject to supply a concrete instance on the fly? I have only worked with constructor injection until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should 'pollute' your DI configuration with this. Instead solve this by using a proxy class that can dispatch the `RequestData` messages to the correct handler implementation:

```cs
public sealed class ServiceDispatcher : IService
{
    private readonly Kernel kernel;
    public ServiceDispatcher(Kernel kernel) {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public void HandleRequest(RequestData data) {
        Type implementationType;
        // custom logic to determine correct IService based on data here..
        // and resolve that implementation from the kernel.
        IService realService = (IService)this.kernel.Get(implementationType);
        realService.HandleRequest(data);
    }
}
```

Now you can bind your `ServiceDispatcher` class to `IService` and allow it to be injected into anyone who depends on `IService`. The dispatcher will ensure that the request is dispatched to the correct implementation.

But you might want to consider using a generic abstraction such as `IService<T>`. Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) for instance.

Comment: Do you mean "public class ServiceDispatcher" right? I like your suggestion. However the problem is just shifted in the HandleRequest implementation of ServiceDispatcher. I mean that I need to manually create an instance of the concrete implementation inside HandleRequest of ServiceDispatcher. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Lorenzo: I'm sorry, ServiceDispatcher is of course a `class`. You should certainly not manually create an instance of the concrete implementation, just resolve that specific implementation from the kernel. How you resolve this depends. You can do it using keyed registrations, or by requesting the concrete type.